# Impressora serial DP-20 com PHP

Tags: php, serial, impressora

Estou montando um script que imprime Cheque com a impressora DP-20 utilizando PHP. Mas só acho tutorial com o uso da DLL deles, nada via porta serial. Alguém sabe como faço isso somente com a porta serial?